# In vs2008 when using the debugger and copying a string's current value, automatically change \\ to \

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In vs2008 when using the debugger and copying a string's current value, automatically change

```
\\
```

to

```
 \
```

I end up having to debug long paths and always get things like

```
 "e:\\eeeee\\blah\\d\\ddd\\fff\\bbbb\\rrrrr\\rrss\\sssss\\somefile.exe"
```

I then I have to go manually replace every doubleslash. Is there a quick dumb way so the variable gets put on the clipboard the way it would look on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the far right of the box, there's a spy glass icon there.  Click it.

That's the Text Visualizer.  It displays the string the way it would appear if you wrote it to, say, the console.  With the escapes applied and \r\n actually breaking the string into the next line.  Copy and paste from that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try working with C# verbatim strings ? i.e. - @"string with \ backslash"?